# Функция, в которой есть аргумент класса Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Когда я начал писать одну программу для тренировки, мне потребовалось сделать так, чтобы из другого файла `Java` кода вызывалась функция. Но так как файл `Java`, из которого я вызываю функцию не привязан ни к какому `Activity` (чтобы можно было его вызвать откуда угодно), мне пришлось прописать в этой функции аргумент класса `Activity`, но при этом когда я прописываю сам `Activity, Android Studio` говорит мне что в коде ошибка

> Expression expected

если кому не понято, вот пример:

`Activity.java`:

```
//вызов функции
function(..., com.example.project.Activity, ...)//выдаёт ошибку где com.example.project.Activity
```

`crViewInActivity.java` (забыл сказать, что эта функция создаёт несколько View в Activity):

```
public static void function(..., Activity where, ...){...; TextView text = new TextView(where);...}`
```

Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, тебе нужно передать в параметрах экземпляр класса Activity из другого класса (не активити)? Тогда можно в MainActivity объявить объект класса MainActivity, в методе `onCreate(...)` присвоить этому объекту this, и создать публичный метод, который возвращает этот объект.

```
private static MainActivity activity;
@Override
public void onCreate (...) {
activity = this;
...
}

public static MainActivity getInstance () { return activity; }
```

А потом с помощью метода `MainActivity.getInstance()` получить нужный объект.

```
function(... , MainActivity.getInstance(), ... )
```

Comment: только на null не забывай проверять в этом случае

Answer (score 0):

Если вызываешь этот метод из Activity.java
то сделай так

```
function(..., this, ...)
```

Comment: Я вызываю его из onClickListener, поэтому не потянет

Comment: тогда Activity.this

Comment: Activity.this тоже выдаёт ошибку (Cannot resolve symbol 'Activity')

Comment: ну напиши подробный вопрос, дай сигнатуру метода, где его вызываешь, тут не экстасенсы сидят же